# MySql Concat First, Middle and Last

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL that contains this:

```
CONCAT(
        tblpeople.FirstName ,
        ' ' ,

    IF(
        tblpeople.Middle <> '' ,
        tblpeople.Middle ,
        ''
    ) ,
    ' ' ,
    tblpeople.LastName ,

IF(
    tblpeople.NameSuffix <> '' ,
    Concat(', ' , tblpeople.NameSuffix) ,
    ''
)
    ) AS `Name` ,
```

The problem is if the Middle field is Null or "" it inserts a space, So a name with a null would look like:
FirstName__LastName (2 spaces).

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
concat_ws(' ',FirstName,MiddleName,LastName) as Name;
```

You may also change the order as you wish also read about concat_ws() function

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a neat built-in function [`concat_ws`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) that takes care of most of the heavy lifting for you by skipping `null`s:

```
CONCAT_WS(' ', FirstName, Middle, LastName)
```

It does not, however, skip empty strings, so you'll have to take care of it explicitly, e.g., with a `case` expression:

```
CONCAT_WS(' ',
          CASE FirstName WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE FirstName END,
          CASE Middle    WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE Middle END,
          CASE LastName  WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE LastName END)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this will help.

```
    Replace(CONCAT(
            tblpeople.FirstName ,
            ' ' ,

        IF(
            tblpeople.Middle <> '' ,
            tblpeople.Middle ,
            ''
        ) ,
        ' ' ,
        tblpeople.LastName ,

    IF(
        tblpeople.NameSuffix <> '' ,
        Concat(', ' , tblpeople.NameSuffix) ,
        ''
    )
        ),'  ',' ') AS `Name`
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, `CONCAT_WS` alone will give you problems with an empty string. I find this a little cleaner than adding several CASE statements:

```
CONCAT_WS(' ', FirstName, NULLIF(MiddleName, ''), NULLIF(LastName, '')) AS Name;
```